# How to *enable* systemd-oomd on a service in system.slice? OOM-kill for non-user .service

Tags: 22.04, systemd, services

So, Jammy 22.04 brought us new goodies, [systemd-oomd](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2022-January/041819.html). Long overdue, IMO... but asking this in 2024 I'm somewhat late to the party, too.

Everyone has asked already how to disable it — yet, I'm **failing to make it work**.

My use-case: a custom *system* service (daemon) under `/etc/systemd/system` which I wrote a unit-file for myself, to have a piece of software running whenever the OS runs, regardless if I'm logged-in or not.

In other words, in `systemd-cgls` tree my `fail2ban.service` runs under `system.slice` — not under `user.slice`.

This permanently-running piece of software is gradually leaking memory.

---

My previous approach, of setting memory limits on it via a [drop-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59842743/what-is-a-drop-in-file-what-is-a-drop-in-directory-how-to-edit-systemd-service) like so:

```ini
# /etc/systemd/system/fail2ban.service.d/mem-limits.conf
[Service]
MemoryAccounting = true

MemoryHigh=155M
MemoryMax=250M
MemorySwapMax=100M
```

— **no longer works**.

I mean, it works, in a way... After upgrade to 22.04 it just effectively **hangs the service process** (which is a python interpreter, but IIUC that doesn't matter) — whereas in 20.04 is was triggering **OOM kill** & auto-restart.

I want this latter behavior back: OOM-kill & restart a service daemon when it exceeds memory limit.

---

I did apt-install `systemd-oomd` package, `systemctl enable --now systemd-oomd.service` as usual, and managed to configure it in `/etc/systemd/oomd.conf`. The command `oomctl` now shows:

```
Dry Run: no
Swap Used Limit: 50.00%
Default Memory Pressure Limit: 10.00%
Default Memory Pressure Duration: 5s
System Context:
        Memory: Used: 3.2G Total: 15.2G
        Swap: Used: 267.2M Total: 7.9G
Swap Monitored CGroups:
Memory Pressure Monitored CGroups:
        Path: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service
                Memory Pressure Limit: 50.00%
                Pressure: Avg10: 0.00 Avg60: 0.00 Avg300: 0.00 Total: 0
                Current Memory Usage: 2.1M
                Memory Min: 0B
                Memory Low: 0B
                Pgscan: 584
                Last Pgscan: 584
```

Beyond that — I've been reading up for hours, and still am completely lost in systemd "memory pressure" options, not seeing clearly what do I need to change for my goal and how.

Do I need to create a dedicated `.slice` separate from system.slice? How ?

Do I need a separate `.scope` ? The meaning of manpages escapes me; both a `.scope` and a `.slice` is a CGroup (v2), alright... but? What's the difference?

How to get my own entry onto the *Memory Pressure Monitored CGroups* list that `oomctl` shows?

Has anyone even managed to get something like this working in 22.04 at all?

Comment: Have you tried fixing root cause of the fail2ban memory leak problem by editing your config?: https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2843

Comment: @DanielT you're misidentifying the root cause. fail2ban is just a good enough example. It's unacceptable for *service manager* that has memory limits feature, to rely on a pinky-promise from the service "I won't ever leak". That promise might fulfill in 1, 2, 3 cases... but will not hold in general.

Comment: A .scope is only created from a command, never a file, while a .slice can. There is no reason to create a .slice for oomd because slices are to stop oomd from killing a big cgroup with many processes. You already have one process in its .service cgroup. oomctl's cgroup display is broken on my computer. The memory limiting is relatively new to systemd and the usage rate is still slowly rising, so I expect most services to have to manage themselves, but the memory limits should work. Another feature of systemd is watchdog timers on services, which you could try to integrate with the service

Comment: "After upgrade to 22.04 it just effectively hangs the service process ... whereas in 20.04 is was triggering OOM kill & auto-restart" ... According to `man systemd.resource-control`, `MemoryHigh` leads to "heavy throttling" and `MemoryMax` leads to the OOM killer being summoned. If that's the case, maybe the gap between the two in your config is just too high for it to be reached quickly given the throttling. Try reducing the gap? Start really small, like `MemoryMax` 1MB more than `MemoryHigh` and increase until you're not OK with the delay.